# jq key name pattern match

Tags: json, jq

I have the following JSON output.

```
{
   "kind":"NodeList",
   "apiVersion":"v1",
   "metadata":{
      "selfLink":"/api/v1/nodes",
      "resourceVersion":"6666628"
   },
   "items":[
      {
         "status":{
            "images":[
               {
                  "names":[
                     "d50d-hlx-app13:3601/n2_agent_centos@sha256:319fea95daa46243c48ad9df4c95aa6b9d3d7a2c5343f465d1a8631ee1df9f50",
                     "d50d-hlx-app13:3601/n2_agent_centos:11.0.2.1"
                  ],
                  "sizeBytes":3223825508
               },
               {
                  "names":[
                     "d50d-hlx-app13:3601/ad_agent_centos@sha256:ebd885ce640a84903ed7a32ae4cd6dff526a074579831634ec9dfbe40b0962ea",
                     "d50d-hlx-app13:3601/ad_agent_centos:11.0.2.0"
                  ],
                  "sizeBytes":1072047699
               },
               {
                  "names":[
                     "gcr.io/google-containers/kube-apiserver:v1.15.3"
                  ],
                  "sizeBytes":206843838
               },
               {
                  "names":[
                     "httpd@sha256:3cbdff4bc16681541885ccf1524a532afa28d2a6578ab7c2d5154a7abc182379",
                     "httpd:latest"
                  ],
                  "sizeBytes":165547282
               },
               {
                  "names":[
                     "gcr.io/google-containers/pause:3.1",
                     "gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.1"
                  ],
                  "sizeBytes":742472
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

I would like to have an output of key and value of items->images->names if one of its keys is "n2_agent_centos".

```
d50d-hlx-app13:3601/n2_agent_centos:11.0.2.1
```

I have tried many ways, all failed. Could someone help me? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Output of key/value but you just have `d50d-hlx-app13:3601/n2_agent_centos:11.0.2.1` in expected output. Please update question with the "exact" output you are looking for.

Comment: Also `"d50d-hlx-app23:3601/n2_agent_centos@sha256:319fea95daa46243c48ad9df4c95aa6b9d3d7a2c5343f465d1a8631ee1df9f50"` contains your search string, how would you want to differentiate that and the one you want

Comment: Also you don't seem to be accepting answers to your questions - https://stackoverflow.com/users/3893836/user3893836?tab=questions. The SO way of saying "thanks" is by acknowledging the right working answer by voting it and marking it "accepted". See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: Sorry, I tried to find how to accept the answer but failed. I do appreciate the help from others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the minor syntactic errors have been fixed in the shown sample, the following produces the result you're expecting:

```
.items[].status.images[].names[]
| select(test("/n2_agent_centos:"))
```

It looks like you were missing `.status`.